# How do I get the corresponding column value for MAX function?

Tags: mysql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following query which gives the latest date_announced for MAX(date_announced) but doesnt give the corresponding value for software_product_build?
how do I get it the corresponding software_product_build value for MAX(date_announced)?

```
   select 
   software_product_build,
   MAX(date_announced) as date_announced
    from software_product_builds
   group by software_product_id
```

[image]

One case:-

```
   select software_product_build,
   MAX(date_announced) as date_announced
    from software_product_builds
    where software_product_build LIKE '%QCA6290.LA.0.1%' group by software_product_id;

OUTPUT:-
|------software_product_build------|-------date_announced------|
--QCA6290.LA.0.1-00001-STD.INT-6---|------2017-03-13 21:13:32---


select software_product_build from software_product_builds where date_announced='2017-03-13 21:13:32';

OUTPUT:-
CI_QCA6290.LA.0.1-03091-STD.INT-61
```

Comment: Classic ["top n of group"](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Comment: @shmosel - so I should say `group by software_productbuild` in addition to software_product_id ?

Comment: What exactly do u want, max date for software_product_id or software_productbuild?

Comment: want to get the software_product_build for max date group by software_product_id?

Comment: could you please paste the output you are getting for your query?

Comment: @Pons - I updated my question with a screen shot of my output,the issue is the sotware_product_build in the output is not from the same row as max date_announced

Comment: Sorry. Still i'm not able to understand the problem completely. Take one case, post the input and output records.

Comment: @Pons - I updated one case.... as you can see the corresponding software_product_build for `date_announced='2017-03-13 21:13:32'; is CI_QCA6290.LA.0.1-03091-STD.INT-61

Comment: what is the data type of date_announced field? If it is date, could you please try these with `date` functions on the `WHERE` clause

Comment: date_announced is `datetime` data type...can you expand on `try these with date functions on the WHERE clause`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get max date for every softwared prduct id then you can find software product build for that max date.

Select spb.software_product_build,
   Tmp.date_announced
    from software_product_builds spb join 
(Select software_product_id,
   MAX(date_announced) as date_announced
    from software_product_builds
   group by software_product_id) as tmp on (tmp.software_product_id=spb.software_product_id and tmp.date_announced=spb.date_announced)

Comment: lets say I want to skip date-announced with values `0000-00-00 00:00:00` where should the check be added in the above query

Comment: You can add where clause at last with your condition plz add something like this where spb.date-announced<> your_condition

Comment: Did you get what you are  trying to do?